# Getting address fields from a Place object

Tags: android, google-maps

We are using Google places android API to allow our users to use the autocomplete widget in order to quickly select addresses.

The widget itself returns a Google Place object which exposes a getAddress() method to return a human readable address string.

Is there a way to extract the address fields (street, city, state etc') from the Place object?

Using the lat/long for reverse geocoding is not 100% accurate (we  saw cases where the house number was different).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using place ID instead of lat/lng in reverse geocoding? It should work much better. Place ID is unique identifier for places.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that there is no Geocoding SDK for Android. I was hoping to be able to do via the Android SDK. I understand that the way to resolve it is to send the PlaceID from the client to the server in order to extract the address elements.

Comment: Place ID can be used with web service, maybe Java client library for Google Maps  web services can help in this task: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java